# Как шагать по двумерному списку зигзагом?

Tags: python

На полотне размерностью 1280 x 900 пикселей задана координатная сетка.
Сетка представляет собой список из двух кортежей:

```
coords = [(0, 256, 512, 768, 1024), (0, 300, 600)]
```

Первый кортеж - координаты по горизонтали.
Второй кортеж - соответственно по вертикали.

Получается, что-то вроде решётки 3 х 5:

- - - - - 
- - - - - 
- - - - - 

Имеется список объектов:

```
objects = []
```

И метод для перемещения:

```
object.move(x, y)
```

> Требуется разместить объекты на сетке.

Не жду готового решения, нужна хотя бы подсказка.

Я пробовал следующее:

```
objects = []
coords = [(0, 256, 512, 768, 1024), (0, 300, 600)]
for i, obj in enumerate(objects):            
    if i >= 0 and i < 5: obj.move(coords[0][i], coords[1][0])
    if i >= 5 and i < 10: obj.move(coords[0][i], coords[1][1])
    if i >= 10 and i < 15: obj.move(coords[0][i], coords[1][2])
```

[Ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1373970/229302) товарища [GrAnd](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/433855/grand) позволил решить задачу.
Мне бы и в голову не пришло использовать **генератор**, а также функцию `zip()`.
В свою очередь, я тоже хочу внести свой вклад и поделиться с сообществом тем,
как применить эти знания на практике.

Допустим у вас есть множество изображений. В моём случае их более 1000.
Чтобы сделать из них страницы с миниатюрами у вас уйдёт целая вечность.
Для создания "превьюшек" я использовал графический редактор **Krita**.
Однако  данный пример может быть легко адаптирован под другой редактор
с поддержкой языка Python.

1. Создаём новый документ размерностью 1280 x 900 пикселей.

> Для документа с иными размерами, нужна будет другая координатная сетка.

> В любом документе изначально присутствуют так называемые слои  по умолчанию, —
> **Paint Layer 1** и **Background**. Первый из них следует заблокировать, нажав на замочек справа. Те слои, в которые будут импортироваться изображения из выбранных вами файлов будут не заблокированными. Именно над ними и будут производиться все операции нашего сценария. Количество файлов для отдельного полотна не должно превышать 15 шт.

2. Открываем редактор сценариев **Tools** > **Scripts** > **Scripter**
3. Запускаем сценарий:

---

```
from krita import *

app = Krita.instance()
doc = app.activeDocument()

app.action('import_layer_from_file').trigger()
topLevelLayers = doc.topLevelNodes()

layers = []

for layer in topLevelLayers:
    if (layer.type() == 'paintlayer' and
        layer.locked() is not True):
            layers.append(layer)

def grid():    
    coords = [(0, 256, 512, 768, 1024), (0, 300, 600)]
    for y in coords[1]:        
        for x in coords[0]:
            yield (x, y)

for (x, y), layer in zip(grid(), layers):
    layer.scaleNode(QPointF(), 256, 300, 'Hermite')
    layer.move(x, y)
    
doc.refreshProjection()
```

Результат работы сценария:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Т.е. требуется округлить координаты так, чтобы они стали принадлежать сетке?

Comment: @GrAnd округлять не надо. У объектов изначально нет координат (допустим они нулевые), т.е. они свалены в стопку в левом верхнем углу полотна. Их нужно просто раскидать по сетке, как в галерее изображений. Количество объектов произвольное (допустим 6 или 7).

Comment: попробуйте пройдитесь по списку ```for x in coords[0]:
    for y in coords[1]:
        object.move(x, y)```

Comment: В качестве ответа подойдёт и какой-нибудь псевдокод, остальное допилю сам. Я давно уже на Python ничего не писал. Всё забыл. А тут такая простая с виду задача, но сломал голову.

Comment: @assert я так уже пробовал. Там проблема в том, что кроме обхода списка с координатами, приходится параллельно делать обход списка из объектов, чтобы их перемещать. В итоге получается какой-то тихий ужас в виде трёхэтажного цикла. Сейчас попробую дополнить вопрос, как я пытался решить задачу.

Comment: @Michael у вас объекты расположены по порядку ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для получения координат можно воспользоваться простейшим генератором.

```
def get_grid_pos():
    coords = [(0, 256, 512, 768, 1024), (0, 300, 600)]
    for y in coords[1]:
        for x in coords[0]:
            yield (x, y)

objects = [obj1, obj2, ...]
for (x,y),object in zip(get_grid_pos(), objects):
    #object.move(x, y)
    print(x,y)
```

Он же, используя itertools.

```
from itertools import product

def get_grid_pos():
    coords = [(0, 256, 512, 768, 1024), (0, 300, 600)]
    for y,x in product(*coords[::-1]):
        yield (x, y)
```

```
0 0
256 0
512 0
768 0
1024 0
0 300
256 300
512 300
768 300
1024 300
0 600
256 600
512 600
768 600
1024 600
```

Comment: Кроме списка из координат, есть ещё список объектов. Генератор позволит обойти список с координатами, однако параллельно нужно шагать по списку из объектов. Кажется в вашем примере, по координатам перемещается один и тот же объект.

Comment: @Michael Никто не мешает идти параллельно. Для этого существует стандартная функция `zip()`.

Comment: Зубодробительный код получился. Сложно было его понять, в итоге всё получилось. В справке не рекомендуют благодарить в комментариях. Однако я просто не могу сдержать эмоции. Столько мучений, — огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если список объектов одномерный, то попробуйте перед проходом по списку координат, создать переменную которая будет считать количество итераций и с помощью срезов обращайтесь к объекту списка

Пример кода:

```
coords = [(0, 256, 512, 768, 1024), (0, 300, 600)]
objects = [f'obj {i + 1}' for i in range(len(coords[0]) * len(coords[1]))]
n = 0
for y in coords[1]:
    for x in coords[0]:
        #objects[n].move(x, y)
        print(f'{objects[n]} : {x}, {y}')
        n += 1
```

Результат выполнения программы :

```
obj 1 : 0 0
obj 2 : 256 0
obj 3 : 512 0
obj 4 : 768 0
obj 5 : 1024 0
obj 6 : 0 300
obj 7 : 256 300
obj 8 : 512 300
obj 9 : 768 300
obj 10 : 1024 300
obj 11 : 0 600
obj 12 : 256 600
obj 13 : 512 600
obj 14 : 768 600
obj 15 : 1024 600
```